# GoogleVis, Geomap Plot error

Tags: r, dictionary

When I want to create the map using the gvisGeoMap() from googleVis, I get error:

```
## Using the google visualization API with R
library(googleVis)
input<- read.csv("data.csv")

select<- input[which(input$Subgroup=="Total 5-14"),]
select<- input[which(input$Subgroup=="Total 5-14 yr"),]

Map<- data.frame(select$Country.or.Area, select$Value)
names(Map)<- c("Country", "Percentage")
Geo=gvisGeoMap(Map, locationvar="Country", numvar="Percentage",
options=list(height=350, dataMode='regions'))

plot(Geo)
#starting httpd help server ... done
#Error in ifelse(interactive(), getOption("browser"), "false") : 
#replacement has length zero
```

The above is the error in the "RGui". The error message in "RStudio" is differet:

```
#object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

and the browser does not fire at all. The HTTP server works fine since I can simply call help pages.( for example ?googleVis will fire up the browser and give the help page). The "Geo" object in the code above is fine and contains the html code only that the plot() does not do what it is supposed to do (I can manually run the html file in the temp folder and see the results). The example above is available [here](http://spatialanalysis.co.uk/2011/02/using-r-to-map-with-google-chart-tools/).

I would appreciate your clues.

Thank you

Comment: Since the file `data.csv` is available on your computer only, we are not able to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thank you very much I forgot to attach the file. But I am getting the same error when running the examples in the vignette(googleVis) pdf. The data.csv is here if anyone has time to run the code above: https://sites.google.com/site/geosciej/Home/data.csv?attredirects=0&d=1

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of correspondance with the the Authors of the packages. It seems that there was a bug that prevented the plot to work properly. The released a new version. You can find the link below. 
TQ

.....
Yesterday evening I realised that with version 0.3.0 of googleVis I unfortunately introduced a bug in RStudio and R on Windows.
The bug has been fixed already and a new version (0.3.1) is available from our project site ([here is the link](http://code.google.com/p/google-motion-charts-with-r/downloads/list)), but not on CRAN yet.

I have put a note on my blog ([here is the link](http://lamages.blogspot.com)) to inform others as well.

I hope this helps.

Best regards

Markus